# String split comparison

Tags: java, string, split

I want to take a String of words that are separated by spaces, and separate each word, and then compare it to another string.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("potato");
    String a = "potato salad";

    String[] x = a.split(" ");

    System.out.println(""+x[0]);
    System.out.println(""+list.get(0));

    if(list.get(0) == x[0])
    {
        System.out.println("they same");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("they not same");
    }
}
}
```

When i print them, they both print the same string
does that mean that the split method returns something other than an array of strings? How can I go around the problem to get the desired result.

Comment: Use `String.equals(String)` instead of `==`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that when you use String comparisons in java to use "a.equals(b)"

```
list.get(0).equals(x[0]);
```